# geom_smooth custom linear model

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, lm

While looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766497/plotting-multiple-regression-lines-based-on-a-variable-in-rs-ggplot2-while-also) issue, I couldn't specify a custom linear model to `geom_smooth`. My code is as follows:

```
example.label <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
example.value <- c(5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 8, 9, 11, 10, 9)
example.age <- c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70)
example.score <- c(90,95,89,91,85,83,88,94,83,90)
example.data <- data.frame(example.label, example.value,example.age,example.score)

p = ggplot(example.data, aes(x=example.age,
                         y=example.value,color=example.label)) +
  geom_point()
  #geom_smooth(method = lm)

cf = function(dt){
  lm(example.value ~example.age+example.score, data = dt)
}

cf(example.data)

p_smooth <- by(example.data, example.data$example.label, 
               function(x) geom_smooth(data=x, method = lm, formula = cf(x)))

p + p_smooth
```

I am getting this error/warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
object 'weight' not found 
2: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
object 'weight' not found
```

Why am I getting this? And what is the proper method of specifying a custom model to `geom_smooth`. Thanks.

Comment: I think the model formula for `geom_smooth` can only be of the form `y ~ f(x)` (e.g., `y ~ x`, which is the default, or `y ~ poly(x, 2)`, `y ~ bs(x, df=4)`, etc.). The formula can only include x and y and they will represent whatever data columns you've passed to `aes` as the x and y aesthetics of the plot. If you want to plot the results of a multivariate regression, you can build a data frame to feed to `predict` and then plot the output using, for example, `geom_line`.

Comment: Do you it worth a try to reshape the data, then use a single column for `x` and `subset` function?

Comment: It's not really a matter of reshaping. All you can really do with `geom_smooth` is plot regressions that include the variables used for your y and x aesthetics plus any categorical aesthetics (e.g., color, shape). For example, in your case, you could do `p + geom_smooth(method=lm, formula=y ~ poly(x, 2))` or `p + geom_smooth(method=lm, formula=y ~ splines::bs(x, df=4))` (though you'll need more data for that one to make sense). These will give you separate regression lines for each level of `example.label`.

Comment: For example, with the `mtcars` data frame, here are regression lines for `mpg` vs. `wt`, but categorized by levels of `vs` and `am`: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour=interaction(vs, am, sep="_"))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE, method="lm")`.

Comment: I see, thanks. Looks like there is no workaround ...

Comment: I've added an answer to expand on the issues discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regression function for a regression model with two continuous predictor variables and a continuous outcome lives in a 3D space (two for the predictors, one for the outcome), while the ggplot graph is a 2D space (one continuous predictor on the x-axis and the outcome on the y-axis). That's the fundamental reason why you can't plot a function of two continuous predictor variables with `geom_smooth`.

One "workaround" is to pick a few specific values of one of the continuous predictor variables and then plot a line for the other continuous predictor on the x-axis for each of the chosen values of the first variable.

Here's an example with the `mtcars` data frame. The regression model below predicts `mpg` using `wt` and `hp`. We then plot the predictions of `mpg` vs. `wt` for various values of `hp`. We create a data frame of predictions and then plot using `geom_line`. Each line in the graph represents the regression prediction for `mpg` vs. `wt` for different values of `hp`. You can, of course, also reverse the roles of `wt` and `hp`.

```
library(ggplot)
theme_set(theme_classic())

d = mtcars
m2 = lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, data=d)

pred.data = expand.grid(wt = seq(min(d$wt), max(d$wt), length=20),
                        hp = quantile(d$hp))
pred.data$mpg = predict(m2, newdata=pred.data)

ggplot(pred.data, aes(wt, mpg, colour=factor(hp))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(colour="HP Quantiles")
```

[image]

Another option is to use a colour gradient to represent `mpg` (the outcome) and plot `wt` and `hp` on the x and y axes:

```
pred.data = expand.grid(wt = seq(min(d$wt), max(d$wt), length=100),
                        hp = seq(min(d$hp), max(d$hp), length=100))
pred.data$mpg = predict(m2, newdata=pred.data)

ggplot(pred.data, aes(wt, hp, z=mpg, fill=mpg)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="yellow", high="blue", midpoint=median(pred.data$mpg))
```

[image]