# Using a covariable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe

```
   year_group total_AF total_strokes proportion_oac    Sex proportion_per_1000_AF
1   2000-2002      373            10    0.402144772 Female              26.809651
2   2003-2005      557             7    0.359066427 Female              12.567325
3   2006-2008      911             9    0.290889133 Female               9.879254
4   2009-2011     1481            17    0.064145847 Female              11.478731
5   2012-2014     2153            29    0.035764050 Female              13.469577
6   2015-2017     2760            30    0.017028986 Female              10.869565
7   2018-2020     3626            42    0.013513514 Female              11.583012
8   2021-2023     1021             8    0.007835455 Female               7.835455
9   2000-2002      889            18    0.428571429   Male              20.247469
10  2003-2005     1397            20    0.382247674   Male              14.316392
11  2006-2008     1969            33    0.347892331   Male              16.759777
12  2009-2011     2686            31    0.093447506   Male              11.541325
13  2012-2014     3802            42    0.041031036   Male              11.046817
14  2015-2017     4476            46    0.025245755   Male              10.277033
15  2018-2020     5300            64    0.014528302   Male              12.075472
16  2021-2023     1342            12    0.013412817   Male               8.941878
```

I have plot them with this code:

```
ggplot(df_strokeAF, aes(x = year_group, y = proportion_per_1000_AF, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Year Group", y = "Proportion per 1000 AF", fill = "Sex") +
  theme_minimal()
```

but now I want to get the same graph but using `proportion_oac` as a covariable (meaning adjusted for `proportion_oac`)

I have tried top use this code

```
ggplot(df_strokeAF, aes(x = year_group, y = proportion_per_1000_AF, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Year Group", y = "Proportion per 1000 AF", fill = "Sex") +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = Sex, color = Sex), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x * proportion_oac, se = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal()
```

but I got this error message:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`
Caused by error:
! object 'proportion_oac' not found
```

Thank you!

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785413/12109788) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848195/12109788) may help. Good luck!

Comment: I understand the lm model, however, I am not how to plot that in mine since I only have a basic relationship between `year_group` and `proportion_per_1000_AF`.

Comment: `lm(y ~ year_group * proportion_oac)` is an ANCOVA model: it fits one regression line for each level of `year_group`. So what `geom_smooth` is supposed to add to the bar plot?